# Meaning of "For Brokes"

Tags: meaning, vocabulary, phrase-meaning

I want to know if the use of "For Brokes" mean what I think because I'm not a native person.

If I want to sell things to people withouth money (broke person), the things that I sell are really cheap so the I could use the phrase "Things for brokes", but I want people to get it only with "For Brokes".

It makes sense? Thanks in advise :)

Comment: If I met "things for brokes", I would be puzzled about what it could possibly mean. I would probably guess, but it is not an English expression.

Comment: Neither Merriam-Webster nor Oxford Dictionaries provide a definition for the noun *broke*. It's only a verb or an adjective. Therefore, you could say *I sell to broke people* or *these things are meant for broke people*. But *for brokes* is completely unnatural.

Comment: As others have said, "broke" is not used as a noun in English, so "things for brokes" makes no sense. If I heard it, I would probably think it meant you were selling broken things (but you wouldn't say it like that either).

Comment: There is the idiom "going for broke", but it has a meaning different from what you apparently want.

Comment: I agree, it's not clear. Also note that *go for broke* (no -s) is a set phrase, meaning something like "put everything on the line for your strongest possible effort". Famously [the motto of the WWII Japanese American 442nd Regiment](http://www.goforbroke.org/learn/history/military_units/442nd.php). So anything "for brokes" is going to recall that saying for some people, which will further confuse the issue.

Answer (score 1):

If they are truly **broke** they don't have any money, what your implying is difficult since if I tried "Buy me you vagrants" or Buy me you paupers" , "Perfect for the ne'er-do-well."  I could be sure of a flaming back lash.

The nearest I can quickly think of and likely to be mildly acceptable is

> "Designed for the less well off" or "less prosperous"

Answer (score 1):

People usually won’t be very attracted to hearing themselves described as ‘broke’ - as that is an undesirable trait. So that could repel your customers.  And you can’t say ‘brokes’ to describe such people, it is not idiomatic (not in use in English).

How about turning ‘broke’ into a more positive trait, like ‘thrifty’?  Thrifty means ‘careful with money; keen on saving money’ so it’s a more appealing way of describing it.

You could say ‘great value items for the thrifty’.

Alternatively you can use ‘broke’ - but soften it with humour, and by directly (but politely) ‘naming the problem’ as in: ‘flat broke? We have great deals for you!’ In this one, we haven’t identified your customers as being ‘broke people’ (which implies a permanent condition and is thus not very... polite!) Instead we suggest that the condition is temporary - flat broke? (- at the moment - implied) and (hurrah!) we offer them a way out - by letting them buy your lower priced products.

Answer (score 1):

No, it doesn't make sense.  "Things for the poor" might fit, and a few other phrasings.  And "things for the thrifty" would imply things for people who are very careful about how they spend their money.

Answer (score 0):

My intuition says that "broke" as a noun is not very common, and this is confirmed by it not being listed at [wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/broke) or any other online dictionary I could find ([dictionary.com](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/broke), [collinsdictionary.com](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/broke) etc).

Building on this, I think the plural "brokes" sounds quite strange as well.